# Should a PCI-DSS certification be renewed?

Tags: pci-dss

I did not find any mention of the need to renew a self-assesment (PCI DSS SAQ-A or SAQ-A-EP) in the [PCI DSS documentation](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/).

There are mentions of renewal for assessors (to maintain their accreditation) and a search over Internet points to random sites with exactly this question (should the certification be renewed) - and the response is "yes, yearly" without any sources.

**Is there a primary source for the need to renew a SAQ-A/A-EP questionnaire?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the intro section 'Scope of PCI DSS Requirement' in v3.2:

> The first step of a PCI DSS assessment is to accurately determine the scope of the review. At least annually and prior to the **annual assessment**, the assessed entity...

A SAQ is completed in lieu of an assessment and given that the assessment requirement is annual, by implication that SAQ requirement is annual as well.

Comment: Thank you - I somehow missed this word when scanning the docs, including the work "annual"